# How to Trigger Youtube API Iframe loader using an OnClick function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a youtube API Iframe that loads on a video trimming script.
Works fine but How can I trigger it based on a click function instead of default on document load.

The reason behind this is that I would like to insert a youtube link in an input box and on click I m trying to update the link ID in **onYouTubeIframeAPIReady()** **videoId** var.

Here's [the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/harish3693/ap5xr3mq/1/) to play around

Here's the code snippet.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/noUiSlider/8.5.1/nouislider.min.css'>
  <style>
     .size
     {
     font-size: 80px;
     font-weight: bold;
     }
     .sizePar
     {
     font-size: 21px;
     }
     .input-size
     {
     width: 355px;
     float: left;
     }
     .button-size
     {
     width: 95px;
     float: none;
     height: 33px;
     }
     .padding
     {
     padding-top: 11px;
     }
     .video-image-size
     {
     width:250px;
     height:auto;
     }
     .center
     {
     text-align: center;
     padding-top: 25px;
     }
     .button-rule
     {
     font-style: normal;
     font-weight: bold;
     vertical-align: middle;
     }
     .button-widht
     {
     width: 116px;
     }
     .allontana
     {
     margin-bottom: 30px;
     margin-top:50px;
     margin-right:15px;
     }
     .separa{
     margin-left: 10px;
     margin-right: 10px;
     }
     .bordered{
     border: 1px solid black;
     }
     body { 
     padding-top: 70px;
     }
     .carousel-inner img{
     margin: 0 auto;
     }
     .navbar-brand{
     font-size: 20pt;
     font-style: bold;
     }
     hr { 
     display: block; 
     height: 1px;
     border: 0; 
     border-top: 1px solid orange;
     margin: 1em 0; padding: 0; 
     }
     .progress {
     border-radius: 0px; 
     height: 10px;
     }
     .progress-bar-warning{
     background: #ffffff;
     }
     .video-image-size-onWatch{
     width:150px;
     height:auto;
     }
     #showcase {
     margin: 0 20px;
     text-align: center;
     }
     #range .noUi-base {
     }
     #range .noUi-background {
     }
     #range .noUi-connect {
     background: #80C9F5;
     box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px rgba(20,20,20,0.65);
     }
     #value-span,
     #value-input {
     width: 50%;
     float: left;
     display: block;
     text-align: center;
     margin: 0;
     }
  </style>



</head>
   <body translate="no" >
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">


    <div>
     <input type="text" id="custom_link" />
     <a id="custom_link_btn" >Submit</a>
    </div>
 

      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-3 text-center">
            <hr>
            <h3>Cut This Video</h3>
            <div class="panel panel-info" style="margin-top:30px;">
               <div class="panel-heading">
                  <h3 class="panel-title">Current Time</h3>
               </div>
               <div class="panel-body">
                  <div id="curTime" style="font-size:20px;">
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-info">
               <div class="panel-heading">
                  <h3 class="panel-title">Select Quality</h3>
               </div>
               <div class="panel-body">
                  <div class="dropdown" id="dropdown" style="font-size:20px;">
                     <!-- dropdown here -->
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-info">
               <div class="panel-heading">
                  <h3 class="panel-title">Cutted duration</h3>
               </div>
               <div class="panel-body">
                  <div id="finalDuration" style="font-size:20px;">
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <!-- player -->
         <div class="col-md-6 text-center" style="padding-top:30px;">
            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
               <!-- 1. The <iframe> (and video player) will replace this <div> tag. -->
               <div id="player" class="embed-responsive-item">
               </div>
            </div>
            <!-- progress bar -->
            <div class="progress">
               <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-primary progress-bar-striped" id="cut-left" style="width: 0%">
                  <span class="sr-only"></span>
               </div>
               <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success progress-bar-striped active" id="played" style="width: 0%">
                  <span class="sr-only"></span>
               </div>
               <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning progress-bar-striped" id="toPlay" style="width: 100%">
                  <span class="sr-only"></span>
               </div>
               <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-primary progress-bar-striped" id="cut-right" style="width: 0%">
                  <span class="sr-only"></span>
               </div>
            </div>
            <!-- 2. The IONrangeSlider container -->
            <div id="range"></div>
            <div id="value-input"></div>
            <div id="value-span"></div>
            <!-- Controls -->
            <div id="controls" style="padding-top:20px;">
               <a href="#" onClick="rewindVideo()" class="separa">
               <i class="separa fa fa-refresh fa-2x"></i>
               </a>
               <a href="#" onClick="backwardVideo()" class="separa">
               <i class="separa fa fa-backward fa-2x"></i>
               </a>
               <a href="#" onClick="playPauseVideo()" id="playPause" class="separa">
               <i class="separa fa fa-play fa-2x"></i>
               </a>
               <a href="#" onClick="forwardVideo()" class="separa">
               <i class="separa fa fa-forward fa-2x"></i>
               </a>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group" style="margin-top:30px;">
               <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Title</span>
               <input type="text" name="title" id="title" class="form-control" value="Bill Maher Live DNC Special Edition: July 27" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" required>
               <div id="inputList"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 text-center" style="padding-top: 30px;">
               <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-top:10px">Cut</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
  <!-- endRow -->
  <script src="https://cpwebassets.codepen.io/assets/common/stopExecutionOnTimeout-1b93190375e9ccc259df3a57c1abc0e64599724ae30d7ea4c6877eb615f89387.js"></script>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/noUiSlider/8.5.1/nouislider.min.js'></script>
  <script id="rendered-js" >
     var tag = document.createElement('script');
     
     tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
     var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
     
     var player;
     var duration;
     function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
       player = new YT.Player('player', {
         height: '360',
         width: '640',
         videoId: 'IP1kr0SCYzk',
         playerVars: { 'start': 0, 'autoplay': 0, 'controls': 0 },
         events: {
           'onReady': onPlayerReady,
           'onStateChange': onytplayerStateChange } });
     
     
     }
     
     function onPlayerReady(event) {
       // event.target.playVideo();
     
       duration = player.getDuration();
       setMoreInfo();
       playPauseVideo();
       setIONrangeSlider();
       checkDomainAndStop();
     }
     
     function onytplayerStateChange(newState) {
       setCorrectImageOnPlay();
     }
     
     /*
      IONrangeSlider
      */
     var fromOld = 0;
     var toOld = duration;
     var slider;
     function setIONrangeSlider() {
     
       var slider = document.getElementById('range');
     
       noUiSlider.create(slider, {
         start: [0, duration], // Handle start position
         step: 1, // Slider moves in increments of '1'
         margin: 3, // Handles must be more than '3' apart
         connect: true, // Display a colored bar between the handles
         behaviour: 'tap-drag', // Move handle on tap, bar is draggable
         range: { // Slider can select '0' to 'duration'
           'min': 0,
           'max': duration } });
     
     
     
       var valueInput = document.getElementById('value-input'),
       valueSpan = document.getElementById('value-span');
       var readValue;
       // When the slider value changes, update the input and span
       slider.noUiSlider.on('update', function (values, handle) {
         if (handle) {
           readValue = values[handle] | 0;
           valueSpan.innerHTML = toHHMMSS(values[handle]);
     
           if (toOld != readValue) {
             toOld = readValue;
           }
     
         } else {
           readValue = values[handle] | 0;
           valueInput.innerHTML = toHHMMSS(values[handle]);
     
           if (fromOld != readValue) {
             fromOld = readValue;
             player.seekTo(readValue, true);
             player.pauseVideo();
             player.playVideo();
           }
         }
       });
     
       // When the input changes, set the slider value
       valueInput.addEventListener('change', function () {
         slider.noUiSlider.set([null, this.value]);
       });
     }
     
     /*
      Player Bar
      */
     function updatePlayerBar() {
       var curTime = player.getCurrentTime();
     
       var cutLeft = fromOld * 100 / duration;
       var cutRigth = (duration - toOld) * 100 / duration;
     
       var played = (curTime - fromOld) * 100 / duration;
     
       var toPlay = 100 - played - cutLeft - cutRigth;
     
     
       document.getElementById("cut-left").style.width = cutLeft + "%";
       document.getElementById("cut-right").style.width = cutRigth + "%";
       document.getElementById("played").style.width = played + "%";
       document.getElementById("toPlay").style.width = toPlay + "%";
     }
     
     /*
      Updates the playback quality
      */
     function updatePlaybackQuality(quality) {
       player.setPlaybackQuality(quality);
       waitForQuality(quality);
     }
     
     
     function waitForQuality(quality) {
     
       if (player.getPlaybackQuality() != quality) {
         setTimeout(function () {waitForQuality(quality);}, 1000);
       } else
       {
         createQualityList(qualityLevels);
       }
     }
     
     function checkDomainAndStop() {
     
       var curTime = player.getCurrentTime();
       document.getElementById('curTime').innerHTML = toHHMMSS(curTime.toString()) + " / " + toHHMMSS(duration.toString());
       var result = toHHMMSS((toOld - fromOld).toString());
       if (result != "NaN:NaN:NaN") {
         document.getElementById('finalDuration').innerHTML = result;
       }
       if (curTime < fromOld) {
         player.seekTo(fromOld, true);
       }
       if (curTime > toOld) {
         player.seekTo(toOld, true);
         pauseVideo();
       }
     
       updatePlayerBar();
     
       // recursively call it.
       setTimeout(checkDomainAndStop, 100);
     }
     
     /*
      Setting more infos
      */
     var waitForLevels;
     var qualityLevels;
     
     function setMoreInfo() {
       waitForLevels = player.getAvailableQualityLevels();
     
       if (waitForLevels.length == 0) {
         setTimeout(setMoreInfo, 1000);
       } else
       {
         qualityLevels = waitForLevels;
         //console.log(qualityLevels);
         createQualityList(qualityLevels);
       }
     }
     
     /*
      converts String to hh:mm:ss or mm:ss
      */
     function toHHMMSS(val) {
       var sec_num = parseInt(val, 10);
       var hours = Math.floor(sec_num / 3600);
       var minutes = Math.floor((sec_num - hours * 3600) / 60);
       var seconds = sec_num - hours * 3600 - minutes * 60;
     
       if (hours < 10) {hours = "0" + hours;}
       if (minutes < 10) {minutes = "0" + minutes;}
       if (seconds < 10) {seconds = "0" + seconds;}
     
       // only mm:ss
       if (hours == "00") {
         var time = minutes + ':' + seconds;
       } else
       {
         var time = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;
       }
     
       return time;
     }
     
     function stopVideo() {
       player.stopVideo();
     
     }
     function pauseVideo() {
       player.pauseVideo();
     }
     
     function playVideo() {
       player.playVideo();
     }
     
     function playPauseVideo() {
       //is playing
       if (player.getPlayerState() == 1) {
         pauseVideo();
       } else
       {
         playVideo();
       }
     }
     
     function setCorrectImageOnPlay() {
       //is playing
       if (player.getPlayerState() == 1) {
         document.getElementById('playPause').innerHTML =
         "<i class=\"separa fa fa-pause fa-2x\"></i>";
       } else
       {
         document.getElementById('playPause').innerHTML =
         "<i class=\"separa fa fa-play fa-2x\"></i>";
       }
     }
     
     function backwardVideo() {
       var curTime = player.getCurrentTime();
       curTime -= 5;
       if (curTime < fromOld) {
         player.seekTo(fromOld, true);
       } else
       {
         player.seekTo(curTime, true);
       }
     }
     
     function rewindVideo() {
       player.seekTo(fromOld, true);
       playVideo();
     }
     
     
     function forwardVideo() {
       var curTime = player.getCurrentTime();
     
       curTime += 5;
       if (curTime > toOld) {
         player.seekTo(toOld, true);
       } else
       {
         player.seekTo(curTime, true);
       }
     }
     //# sourceURL=pen.js
         
  </script>
```

So, as per the above code, I'm trying to get the input value with the click of submit button and update it on **videoId** var, so the trimmable video gets updated. as well.

What I tried:
I tried keeping the whole script inside a function and tried "OnClick", It ran till **2nd console.log print**.